Auto - inherit source generator
I'm currently creating a generator for my .NET framework.
My goal is to have this generator look up and generate some information based on attributes. When the generator is directly referenced, it works correctly.
But I'd like my generator to pass on project that refer to my SDK, not my generator.
Example
if A ref -> B ref -> C ref -> Framework ref -> Generator

I'd like my generator to pass on code of A, B, C and Framework without needs for A (by example) to reference the generator directly.
What parameters, option, or ideas do  I need to setup for this generator to be executed?
Below is the generator of the .csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <!--<Import Project="..\..\..\SharedFrameworkAssmblyInfo.props" />
    <Import Project="..\..\..\SharedFrameworkDemocriteAssemblyInfo.props" />-->
    
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
        <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
        <Description>Democrite core code generator.</Description>
    
        <PackageTags>Democrite;Orleans;Multi-VGrain;Multi-Grain;Multi-Agent;Framework;Core;Abstract;CodeGenerator</PackageTags>
    
        <!-- Define the debugger to use when testing -->
        <IsRoslynComponent>true</IsRoslynComponent>
    
        <DevelopmentDependency>true</DevelopmentDependency>
        
        <EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>true</EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>
        
        <!--<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>-->
        <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
    
        <!-- Generates a package at build -->
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    
        <!-- Do not include the generator as a lib dependency -->
        <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="Templates\RegistryProvider.AssemblyInfo.tpl" />
      <None Remove="Templates\RegistryProvider.tpl" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Templates\RegistryProvider.AssemblyInfo.tpl" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Templates\RegistryProvider.tpl" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- Package the generator in the analyzer directory of the nuget package -->
        <!-- This ensures the library will be packaged as a source generator when we use `dotnet pack` -->
        <None Include="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Update="ErrorManager.tt">
        <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>ErrorManager.cs</LastGenOutput>
      </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
      <Service Include="{508349b6-6b84-4df5-91f0-309beebad82d}" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Update="ErrorManager.cs">
        <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
        <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
        <DependentUpon>ErrorManager.tt</DependentUpon>
      </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>

